# Laravel store data of specific products

Tags: php, laravel, store

I got the following question: on my website I have a page: "shop". And on this page is a foreach that shows me the id and a name of 20 products. On this page is also a button called: "order" which repeats 20 times. So my question here is is it possible in laravel to store once the button is clicked the specific product with their id and name?

```
@foreach
  <td>{{ $shop->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $shop->name }}</td>
  <td><button id="order"></button></td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You could do in external route to store somewhere. ```Session``` or ```Database``` or where ever you want

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what you plan to do with the data once you have access to it. If you plan on using JavaScript, then I would store the id/name in data attributes on the button and access that through a click handler:

```
@foreach
  <td>{{ $shop->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $shop->name }}</td>
  <td><button id="order" data-id="{{ $shop->id }}" data-name="{{ $shop->name }}"></button></td>
@endforeach
```

If not, then I'd create a form for each button with the id/name as hidden form elements:

```
@foreach
  <td>{{ $shop->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $shop->name }}</td>
  <td>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $shop->id }}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $shop->name }}" />
      <button type="submit" id="order"></button>
      </form>
  </td>
@endforeach
```